# Image.asset() versus ImageAsset?

Tags: flutter, darknet

### Problem Description

I have no clue when I need to use and `Image.asset()` and when I need to use `AssetImage()`. For me, it seems like both of these are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Image.asset` is a kind of `Widget/StatefulWidget`. You can use Image.asset() directly while `AssetImage` is a provider of an image type, which helps in retrieving an image from a source location/path and you can't use `AssetImage` directly.